# Connecting spotify api with gpt 3 api on wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, spotify, gpt-3

I'm working on a WordPress website and trying to make Spotify and GPT-3 play nice together on my site. It's a bit tricky, and I could use some help. I'm looking for an easy way to grab info from Spotify—like playlists and songs—right into my WordPress site.

Any WordPress plugins that can help accomplish this task?
If so, how can I use the plugin to do this?
If not, how can I accomplish this through code?